# bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run: permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, root, xampp

I am trying to perform the above command and getting denied with the permission. can anyone help?
`bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run: permission denied`

this is the output of `ls -l xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run` it shows like this: `-rwxrw-r-- 1 username username 141105278 jul 12 10:23 xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run`

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run`to your question.

Comment: you probably miss the execution permission; as said @SorenA , check with `ls -l xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run` if you have the execution permission. Don't forget it's an executable, it can need some privilege with a little `sudo`

Comment: `sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run` to make the script executable and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

1. In the file properties->Permissions tab selected the group permission to read and write
2. checked the checkbox next to execute option.

[See the screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd9jD.png)

then opened a terminal in the directory and typed the following commands

```
sudo su
./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.7-0-installer.run
```

[See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGwrq.png)

installation started like a charm!

Note: I tried this when the file was in a non-system partition. It didn't work. So I copied the file into my home directory and did the above things. they worked.